# new HttpConfiguration(); fails with Nunit but not MsTests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, asp.net-web-api, mstest

I am trying to make a Test Project using Nunit to test my Webapi 1 routes. The problem is that I always get this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tryed to run the code with MsTests (a new testProject) and the exception is not there.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Http;
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        }
    }
}
```

So on that exemple i can run both MsTest and Nunit.   MsTest works fine but Nunit doesn't. anyone knows why ?
I also tryed with Gallio + MBUnit and it doesn't work.

More info:
FrameworkTarget:  .net 4.0
System.Web.Http version 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the reference to Newtonsoft.json and in the app.config/web.config  add these lines:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

It seems like with MsTests these steps are not required but with Nunit they are.
The same modification apply if i try to create this object from a plain ConsoleApplication.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Daneau's answer. NUnit does not load the .config file unless it's named correctly according to the convention here:
http://nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.6.4

According to their instructions, copy your app.config file in your NUnit project and give it the exact same name as your project. In your case the name should be "UnitTestProject1.config".  Put it in the root folder along with the original app.config file.

Now bindingRedirect will be properly loaded.